# Powershell; test for Null in obj property before assignment

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to assign an object property to a string with this code:

```
    $VMDynMemMax = Get-SCVirtualMachine $_.Name | Select -Expand DynamicMemoryMaximumMB
```

but sometimes the DynamicMemoryMaximumMB could be null.  When this happens, the script throws an InvalidArgument error.  I believe this is because I am using -Expand and Null cannot be expanded.

I am using -Expand because I later use the string $VMDynMemMax in a custom table using label and expression.  If I do not use the -Expand, the values that are produced in the table come out as

`@{VariableName=Value}`

rather than just

```
Value
```

How should I go about checking the property for Null values before expand or assignment?

Comment: `$VMDynMemMax = (Get-SCVirtualMachine $_.Name).DynamicMemoryMaximumMB` will work and assign `$null` to the variable if the property doesn't exist. That still might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the IsNullOrEmpty method under [string] to test for a Null value and it isn't the case, then perform an action.

```
If (-NOT [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($VMDynMemMax)) {
    #DO WORK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@TessellatingHeckler - Using `(Get-SCVirtualMachine $_.Name).DynamicMemoryMaximumMB`  worked for me!